# Where Kotlin version in lintAnalyzeDebug comes from?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin-multiplatform

I've upgraded from Kotlin 1.7 to Kotlin 1.9 in my KMM project.
though I have Gradle 7.6
AGP 7.4.2

After the upgrade lintAnalyzeDebug task reports error on every dependency: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.

I understand that I can disable the lint check, but I want to keep it if it is possible. I understand that the 1.7.1 is used by the version of Gradle. I cannot upgrade Gradle, because Idea does not work with Gradle 8 correctly. What I am not understand is why this error is thrown. Everything else works with Kotlin 1.9 well. Why only lint has problems?

Is there any place where I need to fix Kotlin version used for lint?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can update the lint version used by adding:

```
android.experimental.lint.version=8.1.0-rc01
```

to gradle.properties.

This is needed because the default lint version included in AGP 7.4.2 (and AGP 8.0.2 even) links with kotlin-compiler plugins for 1.7 which handles up to and including kotlin 1.8.
So to support kotlin 1.9.x you need a lint version that at least links kotlin-compiler plugin 1.8, 8.1.0-rc01 for example.

More information in this google tracker issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/185418482

Comment: Really well dug out! Can be next to impossible to find solutions to these obscure problems.

Answer (score -1):

You can try adding this to your `build.gradle` file

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        lintChecks = ["NewerVersion"]
    }
}
```

where `NewerVersion` is the version of the lint that works well with Kotlin 1.9

Comment: lintOptions is depricated. And there is no property lintChecks or lint or lintOptions.

Comment: you can use `lint` block instead of `lintOptions` - https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.4/com/android/build/api/dsl/Lint

Comment: I do not mind using obsolete lint, but there is no lintChecks. You can see it yourself on the link you posted.